# S11108 Circuit Design Logic

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, measurement, hardware, image-sensor

This is my first post and also my first dip into electrical engineering, and I wanted to ask if you have any suggestions on the circuit I have designed. As a background, I'm a Computer Science student, so I have no issues if you suggest any programming-orientated approaches.

The purpose of the circuit is to drive a CMOS S11108 linear image sensor so I can send the pixel data through the serial connection on an "Arduino Nano Every" board to a Raspberry Pi, where it would be output.

I use an LM358P op-amp to perform some basic thresholding on the analogue signals as I was planning on using the data to measure gaps in objects like a nut or between two strips of tape, and I wanted to be able to control this threshold value using a potentiometer.

If I was to pick more concise questions they would be:

1. Is using an Arduino Nano Every board the best pick for a driver board? I've heard mixed things online, and but apart from the odd exception. I've never really seen them used in sensing applications like this.
2. Is the op-amp really the best component for the job of thresholding the voltage value?

[image]

[Google Drive link to schematic and S11108 datasheet](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nIQr4zYgdKwpUESumwOak8UBdYV0fIJP?usp=sharing).

Comment: My first question is: can an arduino even handle the amount of data coming from an image sensor? They're not particularly fast devices.

Comment: @Alex Can you write a specific question?

Comment: @Hearth I'm unsure with this particular sensor myself as I haven't seen much material online for this component, but I have seen some info on a TCD1304 linear image sensor which was wired up with a teensy board and it worked quite well. Although this sensor has a higher resolution than the TCD1304 before I did any designs I asked some people on hackday.io about the project and this what they have said about the sensor-Arduino combination: "The minimum listed toggle frequency f(CLK) from the datasheet is 200 KHz which is well within the direct programming speed of an arduino".

Comment: @VoltageSpike Good point, although I cant pick an individual question. If I was to pick more concise questions they would be: 1. Is using an Arduino Nano Every board the best pick for a driver board? I've heard mixed things online, and but apart from the odd exception. I've never really seen them used in sensing applications like this. 2. Is the op-amp really the best component for the job of thresholding the voltage value? I don't have much experience with Analogue electronics so was wondering if there were any suggestions?

Comment: I would grab a webcam, any webcam, pick a line out of it, convert to grayscale, and analyze that. A couple lines of Mathematica will do that - quite literally, and you’ll have a dynamic document that shows the processed data etc. You can also directly apply neural networks to the line vector and so on. I’d not touch custom hardware before it’s well established the image processing method works.